# Gzip compression on Apache using .htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, compression, gzip, lamp, htaccess

As per http://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html i'm trying to enable gzip compression on apache webserver adding code mentioned below in .htaccess, but it's not working ; can you please suggest how to fix this?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running mod_deflate?  Depending on your OS, run `httpd -M` or `apache2ctl -M`.

Comment: No I'm not running mod_deflate. is there any way other than running mod_deflate?

Comment: Well, if you're not running mod_deflate, your `IfModule mod_deflate.c` statement isn't being processed - so that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two options.  First, I would encourage you to just load the `mod_deflate` module.  Add the following line to your `httpd.conf` file.

`LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so`

Otherwise, there is an alternative - `mod_gzip`.  It is a an external extension that you'll have to download the source code, compile, and load using a line in your `httpd.conf` file.  Something like:

`LoadModule gzip_module mod_gzip.so`

Here are two StackExchange threads that discuss `mod_gzip` vs. `mod_deflate`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173147/mod-deflate-or-mod-gzip-which-should-be-used) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255453/mod-deflate-vs-mod-gzip)

Good luck.